# Linear Transformations Extension of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:P2(R)→P2(R) $be the transformation linearly extending
>
> $T(x) = x-2$
>
> $ T(x^2−x)=x+2x^2$
>
> $T(x−2+x^2)=-1-x^2$
>
> Compute $T(2+x^2)=...$

Hello Everyone, I have this question to solve but I'm kinda confused how to do it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by “Extend Polynomials”?

Comment: $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is space of polynomials of degree $\le 2$ (hopefully). The basis is $\{1,x,x^2\}$ using the given data you can compute the values of the transformation on the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

The trick here consists in expressing the polynomial $x^{2} + 2$ in terms of $\{x,x^{2}-x,x^{2}+x-2\}$. Precisely speaking, one has
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + 2 = ax + b(x^{2}-x) + c(x^{2}+x-2) = -2c + (a-b+c)x + (b+c)x^{2}
\end{align*}

Solving the corresponding system of equations, we get that $a = 3$, $b = 2$ and $c = -1$.

Finally, we are able to compute $T(x^{2} + 2)$
\begin{align*}
T(x^{2} + 2) = 3T(x) + 2T(x^{2}-x) - T(x^{2}+x-2) = \ldots
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**

Based on the given comment, here it is the full answer to the question:
\begin{align*}
T(x^{2} + 2) & = 3T(x) + 2T(x^{2}-x) - T(x^{2}+x-2)\\\\
& = 3(x-2) + 2(2x^{2} + x) + (x^{2} + 1)\\\\
& = -5 + 5x + 5x^{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: I couldn't find any examples regarding this question so I couldn't do it, can you please finish it so I can use it as an example and solve other problems similar to this one.